# Angular 10 - Server Sent Events - Missing EventSource

Tags: angular, provider, eventsource

I'm using Angular 10 and trying to listen to server-sent events from a node.js REST server.  I'm a noob with Angular (this is a school project.)  Anyway, all the tutorials I've found create a service that implements the EventSource and subscribes to the chunks as they are received.  Everything compiles ok, but when I browse to a page that uses the service I get this error "NullInjectorError: No provider for EventSource".  Can anybody provide a reference that might help or tell me what I need to do to get past the error?

To be clear, I am not creating a new EventSource class but using what I understand to be a JavaScript built-in class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource).

Removing "private _eventSource: EventSource" resolved the problem, which raises another question (I think I may have stumbled on my answer.)  Is it the case that one cannot declare a variable of a built-in JavaScript type like EventSource?

Here is my code...

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Facility } from '../models/facility.model'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyClass {

  constructor( 
    private _http: HttpClient,
    private _zone: NgZone,
    private _eventSource: EventSource   // removing this resolved the error
  ) { }


  getMyEventSourceStream() {

    return new Observable((observer) => {
      const eventSource = new EventSource(this._summaryUrl);

      eventSource.onopen = (event) => {
        console.log(event);
      }

      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log(event);
        this._zone.run(() => {
          observer.next(event);
        })
      };

      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
          observer.error(error);
        })
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to help if we could see some code fragments but looking at error

> NullInjectorError: No provider for EventSource

There are some missing dependencies in Angular dependency injection [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#create-and-register-an-injectable-service), which might mean that somewhere in your code you have created service class like
`export class EventSource { ... }` and then in another one you are trying to provide it in constructor

```
class AnotherClass{
  constructor(private myEventSource: EventSource)
}
```

but for it to work you would need to let DI know about your new class [docs](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-a-service) which could be done by adding annotation

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EventSource {
    ...
}
```

Other possibility is that you wanted to use already available javascript class `EventSource` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) then instead of passing it to constructor try to simply create it in constructor

```
class AnotherClass{
  private myEventSource
  constructor(){
    this.myEventSource = new EventSource(..)
  }
}
```

If that was the problem you can later provide it in Angular DI as well this was proposed as potential quick fix.